# "Indispensable for" vs, "indispensable to"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, to-for

What is the difference between "indispensable to" and "indispensable for"?

Likewise, between "it is important to me" and "it is important for me", which one is correct?

Comment: These are not terms used commonly; they must have been made up by your teacher or one of their teachers. They may be referring to the _for...to_ complementizer that marks infinitives; that's all I can tell. As for the two sentences, both are correct; either preposition may be used with _important_; _for_ may have an additional meaning in context.

Comment: Oh, sorry i wrongly typed "indispensable" to "indispensible".  The original sentence was " His article was indispensable to the company". But I came to wonder if it was possible to change 'to' to 'for' without changing the meaning, or if the meaning changes, what would be the difference.  This is kind of a same question with the second question.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, and you're right, it's the same in both cases. When an example sentence is given in context, things can often be understood. But with only strings of a couple words, there's no way anybody can understand your question. Tje spelling isn't important; the context is. You should **always** provide a full example sentence and a context for it when asking about meaning or grammar.

Comment: Related: [“Importance of” vs. “Importance for”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15926/importance-of-to-or-importance-of-for), as well as several of the questions in our [dedicated tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-for), which I'm adding to your question.

Comment: Thank you Dwight! Are you the Dwight from the office?

Answer (score 3):

In many contexts, it makes no semantic difference whether we use ***for*** or ***to*** after words like *indispensable, important, essential,* etc. But sometimes there *is* a potential distinction...

> 1: *"It's important **to** John to vote"*
>    2: *"It's important **for** John to vote"*

I think most native speakers would agree that #1 always means *it matters a lot to **John** that he votes*, whereas in #2 it's possible John himself doesn't care one way or the other (but it does matter to ***the speaker*** and/or ***other people in general*** and/or it's *important within the context of some ethical framework*).